# Drools support in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, drools

I'm trying to use IntelliJ IDEA with legacy project with Drools files but I'm not successful in this.

I added [Drools framework](http://www.drools.org) to the module with `*.drl` files and... nothing. I can't reformat `*.drl` files, don't have any navigation, no code completion etc.

I expected to see ability to add Drools facet to my module, specify `*.drl` files and then work with Drools files basically as with Spring framework.

So what Drools support actually IntelliJ IDEA has?

Answer (score 8):

Do you have the Drools plugin enabled in IntelliJ IDEA?

To check it, you need to navigate to `File -> Settings -> Plugins`, then search for Drools. The plugin is called JBoss Drools support. If it's not enabled, enable it.

Comment: Yes, I have it activated. Is there any description of this plugin? What should I expect from it?

Comment: The plugin adds coding assistance for the drl files. [link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+JBoss+Technologies+in+IntelliJ+IDEA#GettingStartedwithJBossTechnologiesinIntelliJIDEA-DroolsExpert)
If you add framework support, but don't activate the plugin, then the drl files will work only like text files.

Activating the plugin and adding the framework support should do the trick, I don't know why it isn't working for you. Have you tried right clicking on your project and select `Add framework support...` ?

Comment: @S0m30n3 Does idea community gives chance to install drools plugin? ...I can't detect one on the market place.

Comment: I couldn't find it on the marketplace either but I see it as a bundled plugin in IDEA Ultimate version. So if it's not on your plugin list then I think it can't be installed in Community edition.

Answer (score 0):

Drools support seems to come with Intellij Ultimate edition as it plugin is part of JBoss.
The issue I face in Intellij Community edition is that I could edit .drl file,
what is I did was to change the file extension from .drl to .txt edit file and change back to .drl.
I could compile and run the application.

Answer (score 0):

It won't let me comment but I couldn't find the plug in either until after I updated my intellij, then it was there.  Try going to help, check for updates and then look again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29763226)