# Drools support Intellij version: 2017.1.5

Tags: intellij-idea, drools

In the most recent version of intellij (2017.1.5) it appears that I can't add the drools plugin anymore to work with drl files. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534153/drools-support-in-intellij-idea) solution that worked in the old version. But currently I can't seem to find the plugins section in Intellij in order to add the JBoss Drools support. I do get a popup from Intellij however notifying me that the 'Ultimate' edition of Intellij does offer support for Drools whenever I create a *.drl file; see creenshot:
[image]

Currently I don't know if this means that JBoss is now more commercial and tries to sell more of the Ultimate edition of their software or that I'm not looking in the right place. Hope someone can help.

Comment: No info so far?