# Drools UI for editing rules file with intelliJ env

Tags: intellij-idea, drools

I'm using drools with intelliJ.

I understand there's also a UI to edit the rule file.

How do I use it with IntelliJ environment?

Comment: Check that [drools plug-in is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39574491/104891) and the file extension you are editing [is mapped to Drools file type](https://i.imgur.com/GmK8hhK.png).

Comment: It is.I can edit the drl file. And it works. But how is that related to the GUI editor?...

Comment: Are you looking for [this feature](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206869349-Generate-BPMN-2-0-diagram)?